# PDO parameterized query on access in linux not working

Tags: ms-access

This is with php ,  PDO on  MS Access .mdb with linux drivers , have this code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM F_ART WHERE CODART = :id";
    $result = $this->cache->get($sql . $id);
    if(!$result){
        $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $stm->execute();
        $result = $stm->fetchAll();
        $this->cache->set($sql.$id,$result);
    }
    return $result;
```

which output this:

```
Error at Line : syntax error near ?
syntax error near ?
Got no result for 'SELECT * FROM F_ART WHERE CODART = ?' command
```

with normal query string it works :

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM F_ART WHERE CODART ='" . $id . "'";
    $result = $this->cache->get($sql . $id);
    if (!$result) {
        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->fetchAll();
        $this->cache->set($sql.$id,$result);
    }
    return $result;
```

where is the problem?

Comment: perhaps you have some poison in $id variable. try to output $sql value to error_log

Comment: also, with $this->cache->set($sql.$id,$result) you will have something definitely bad

Comment: Sorry , I made a mistake copying the code , just edited with the correct parametered version , how can I  output the $sql string with paramater binded?

Comment: The same code in mysql , works